# How do you loop a frame by frame grease pencil animation a limited number of times?

Tags: grease-pencil, timeline

I'm working on an animation where the character is running for 5 or 6 seconds. The actual animation is drawn frame by frame, and it consists of 15 individually drawn grease pencil frames. However, after 6 seconds of looping, the scene changes into something else. I've tried using Offset Time modifier, but it gives me two problems -

1. it loops indefinitely with no option for me to add an end frame
2. when I manually add a blank frame after 6 seconds, the Offset Time modifier no longer loops the animation.

Is there an effect, or modifier, or some type of setting Blender has that will let me loop this for 6 seconds and then stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert keyframes to switch any modifier on and off at a given time. It's not really obvious but on the top line, to the right the modifiers name, are two icons, a screen and a camera.

[image: modifier switches]

The screen makes the modifier be visible in the viewport and the camera makes it visible during render. By hovering the mouse over the icons and pressing <kbd>I</kbd> (like "insert") you can keyframe their current state.

So, in your case (assuming you're at 24fps) go to frame `144` and with the mouse over the icon press <kbd>I</kbd>. Then move to frame `145`, disable the modifier and insert another keyframe. Because you likely want it to stop looping on screen and also in the render, you'll have to do that for both the screen and the camera icon.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!! That was driving me totally nuts, but your answer solved this instantly. Animating different things in the same Blender file is so much easier now - you are literally my savior! Thank you thank you thank you